# Erro ao gerar relatório Dynamic Report - No query execute factory registered for the 'sql' language

Tags: java

Quando eu gero um relatório utilizando dynamic report através da IDE, o relatório é gerado perfeitamente. Mas quando eu gero um relatório fora da IDE acontece um erro na geração do mesmo.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer
>   factory registered for the 'sql' language. at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1163)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:630)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:791)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ReportTransform.transform(ReportTransform.java:90)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.transform(JasperReportDesign.java:98)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.(JasperReportDesign.java:77)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperReportDesign.(JasperReportDesign.java:69)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReportDesign(JasperReportBuilder.java:260)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.getJasperParameters(JasperReportBuilder.java:287)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:298)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:596)
>   at
>   net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:516)
>   at at com.versul.runnables.ReportsProcess.run(ReportsProcess.java:72)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Você sabe que você não precisa ficar apagando as perguntas e criando uma nova né? Basta clicar no botão **[edit]**

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Percebi que você excluiu tentativas anteriores de postagem desta pergunta. Isso não é necessário, você pode editar a pergunta em vez de apagar e postar novamente. Tem um link para editar logo abaixo das tags. E caso alguém faça uma edição com a qual você discorda, você pode desfazê-la.

Comment: isso Acontece com Qual IDE mesmo?